# how to (INSERT) data in this table in entity framework code first?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

**-------------------

using EF 6

-------------------**

I have 3 table :

1) **Users**

```
public class Users 
{
    [Key,Required, MaxLength(50)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(128)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(128)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

2) **Roles**

```
public class Roles 
{
    [Key,Required, MaxLength(50)]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
}
```

3) **UsersInRoles** //My Problem.

```
public class UsersInRoles 
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Users"), Required]
    public string FKUserName { get; set; }
    public virtual Users Users { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Roles"), Required]
    public string FKRoleName { get; set; }
    public virtual Roles Roles { get; set; }
}
```

**Now my question is how to insert record in UsersInRoles table ???**

i use following code but don't insert any data in table!
even don't show any errors!

```
    List<UsersInRoles> BUsersInRoles = new List<UsersInRoles>
    {
        new UsersInRoles { FKUserName="User1", FKRoleName="Role1"},
        new UsersInRoles { FKUserName="User2", FKRoleName="Role2"}
    };

    foreach (UsersInRoles BIR in BUsersInRoles)
    {
        db.UsersInRoles.Add(BIR);
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
```

Thanks.

**Update**:
*i have found a error :*

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.UsersInRoles_dbo.Roles_FKRoleName". The conflict occurred in
>   database "AriyaRad", table "dbo.Roles", column 'RoleName'. The
>   statement has been terminated.

Comment: Does Role1 and Role2 exist in the Roles table?

Comment: thanks  Evonet.  Before this scenario, i insert Role and Role in role table.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem!
The reason was i define single string value for Foreign Key but try to insert list of string value!

```
db.UsersInRoles.Add(new UsersInRoles {FKUserName="User1",
                FKRoleName="Role1", ApplicationName="PSCMS"});  
db.SaveChanges();
```